# ImageMagick fails on php but works in shell

Tags: imagemagick

I've this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -density 200 /singlePage.pdf -colorspace RGB -verbose -geometry 1155 -quality 10 -limit area 100mb singlePicture.jpg
```

When executing with php (via browser) it has no result output (executing with php function exec()).

When executing the same command on shell, it works perfectly.

I tried another pdf file, which works on php and shell. The only difference is the filesize.

1,0806 MB => Works
1,0962 MB => Not Works

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So this:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -density 200 /singlePage.pdf -colorspace RGB -verbose -geometry 1155 -quality 10 -limit area 100mb singlePicture.jpg
```

implies that the singlePage.pdf file is located on the root of your filesystem. I doubt that is true. My guess is the "/singlePage.pdf" path is wrong.